# Issue with pandas to_datetime function

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a column that is unix timestamps.  I want to convert this column to just dates in a `%y-%m-%d` format.  Just to test the `to_datetime()` function I did the below, which works as expected and gives me the column in a format like this `2015-05-12 00:11:30` :

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
```

When I add in the `format` argument Like below, I get an error:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s', format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

The error is `ValueError: time data 1431389490 does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'`

How can I strip off the hours, minutes and seconds so I am only left with 2014-05-12?

Comment: do you want to store the dates as a string, or just format their display in the repr?

Comment: @PaulH I think I just want to to format their display.

Comment: in the repr or in a file?

Comment: @PaulH sorry, but I don't know what "repr" is.  I'm using an ipython notebook, so however the dataframe is displayed there

Comment: ok yeah -- "repr" is just a method for each object that determines how it will be displayed. dataframes have a special repr method just for notebooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to extract just the date, you can do that in a second step after converting to datetime:

```
x = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([1431389490]), unit='s')
# Datetime columns have a `.dt` attribute, with useful properties
# and methods for working with dates
x.dt.date
Out[7]: 
0    2015-05-12
dtype: object
```

This will discard the information about hours and minutes, but you will be able to work with the resulting column/series easily because the result is a `datetime.date` object, e.g. subtracting to find the number of days between your column and a certain date.

If you want to keep the information about hours and minutes, but only *display* it differently, I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says my series does not have a `dt` attribute

Comment: Just a thought, why not do `x = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([1431389490]), unit='s').dt.date` in one step?

Comment: @Meepl, what version of pandas? works for me on v0.16.1

Comment: @Meepl it will only have the `.dt` attribute *after* you create it with `pd.to_datetime`, only datetime columns have the dt attribute

Comment: And yes, it might be new in v0.15/v0.16.

Comment: Hmm, okay - I am on 0.14.1